# PHP return value inconsistent: true becomes false

Tags: php, boolean

I've run across an extremely weird problem in PHP. The behaviour makes me think it's a bug, but it's so fundamental that it really shouldn't be.

Amongst other code, I have these two functions:

```
// Check admin authentication
// Used to check user has access to a page
function function_check_admin(){
    function_start_session();

    $isadmin = function_is_admin(NULL);
    error_log("got return of ".intval($isadmin)." which is of type ".gettype($isadmin));
    $isnotadmin = !(function_is_admin());
    if($isnotadmin){
        echo echo_error("You are not authorised to access this page.");
        exit;
    }
}

...

// Check if user is an administrator
// pass access parameter if access already loaded and known
function function_is_admin($access = NULL){
    if (!function_is_logged_in()){
        return False;
    }

    // Load access
    if ($access === NULL)
        $access = account_access();

    error_log("access is ".$access);
    $return = ($access <= ADMIN);

    error_log("admin is ".$return);
    return $return;
}
```

Sometimes, when function_check_admin() is called, it throws the error and quits. The error log reports:

```
[error] access is 0
[error] admin is 1
[error] got return of 0 which is of type boolean, referer: ...
```

Additionally, if I replace

```
    return $return;
```

with

```
    return TRUE;
```

The behaviour and error log remains unchanged. The return value of true suddenly becomes false in the caller function.

The problem only occasionally crops up. The exact same code works perfectly fine on the development copy of the site.

And weirdest of all, when it occurs, it can be fixed by removing all cookies related to the site.

I'm running PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2013 05:50:20)

Does this have any precedence? Any ideas what might be happening, and what a work around is?

Comment: Why name functions with `function_`? It's indeed a function.

Comment: I have a large body of code with several files, and several 'libraries' of standard functions. 'function_' identifies which file the function declaration is in. I'm open to suggestions of better organisational structures.

Comment: Namespaces, PSR: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php, http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/